# git submodule update from wrong remote

Tags: git

I cloned Blender repo that has 4 submodules

```
[submodule "release/scripts/addons"]
    path = release/scripts/addons
    url = ../blender-addons.git
    ignore = all
[submodule "release/scripts/addons_contrib"]
    path = release/scripts/addons_contrib
    url = ../blender-addons-contrib.git
    ignore = all
[submodule "release/datafiles/locale"]
    path = release/datafiles/locale
    url = ../blender-translations.git
    ignore = all
[submodule "scons"]
    path = scons
    url = ../scons.git
    ignore = all
```

and then i created branch from specific commit via `git checkout -b branchname <commit>`.

Then i added new github remote and pushed that branch to that github repo.

Then i noticed i need even clone one submodule (scons for build), so i used `git submodule update --init scons`, but it tried to connect to github, which is obviously wrong, because it must be cloned from that original remote.

**Q**: I still can't get it to clone **scons** from that original repo. It still trying to clone from github, why? The other submodules work as expected.
I am not sure if it could be because i tried to run that `git submodule` command first time from that new branch i created and not from master.
I tried even from master but still same behaviour (connecting to github).

Comment: Why not provide a full path to repository? I.e. `protocol://host:port/project/submodule` instead of ambiguous`../submodule`?

Answer (score 0):

If your example .gitmodules file is copied verbatim, specifically if the URLs are 'relative' URLs (i.e. they start with either `./` or `../`) then that will cause the `git submodule update` command to try to pull the submodule from the same base URL as the superproject, in this case GitHub (see http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule for details on submodules)

Could you clarify what you mean by

> The other submodules work as expected.

As they too appear to have relative URLs and, as such I would expect them to fail in the same way.

What I would advise, is to update the .gitmodules file to use full URLs which point to the original repo location. That should fix any problems fetching from another URL.